# beautifulSoup filter some data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

===changed
after getting the source of page, lets call it src

I use bs4 for parsing:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src)
```

the think is that I'm getting the filtered data.

Example: look at the source of this url="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000905/"
after using bs4:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src)
```

the filtered data is "Known For" and "Related News" and all what under it.
so when opening soup I see the upper part of the page.
(see [python,not getting full response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102696/python-not-getting-full-response))
I still want to work with bs4 (I have too)
any suggestion?

thanks for help.

Comment: Be more specific with your question. Tell us what you tried, what you expected and what you got.

Comment: Now that you've added a little more, I still don't see what you're asking. Is this not just a duplicate of your question from four hours earlier?

Comment: @Chris Morgan this is not duplicated because I'm trying to explain what is the problem of the first case. and looking for solution for it. 
so: why soup is not full?>

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions? yes, use the library as specified in [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: this is the lib that i'm using and makes problems !!

Comment: @aminonsh But you haven't *explained* your problem *at all*!