# Python urllib2 not obtaining full response (PDF)

Tags: php, python, pdf, urllib2, x-sendfile

I am trying to download a PDF by hitting a URL. Say my URL looks like this: http://foo.bar/this/downloads/pdf

If I hit the URL directly, the browser downloads the PDF, with no problem. However, if I try to get the PDF using `urllib2.urlopen` I get an incomplete file.

```
url = "http://foo.bar/this/downloads/pdf"
sock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = sock.read()
with open('/tmp/test.pdf', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

The last 3 lines of /tmp/test.pdf look like this (and it looks like this in the variable `content`):

```
0000778731 00000 n 
0000778751 00000 n 
000
```

But the actual file that I downloaded from the browser looks like this:

```
0000778731 00000 n 
0000778751 00000 n 
0000778772 00000 n 
...
%%EOF
```

Every single PDF, regardless of size, seems to cut off somewhere in this final combination of numbers.

I have tried the following solutions, and both do not work. I believe the reason does not have to do with the way in which the data is read, but the fact that the `urllib2` is not even getting the full response in the first place.

[python,not getting full response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102696/python-not-getting-full-response)

[urllib2 not retrieving entire HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824069/urllib2-not-retrieving-entire-http-response)

Another thing that may be a factor (though I'm unsure) is the way the PDF is sent to the browser. To my knowledge, the PDF is sent using PHP x-sendfile. I am just confused as to why the PDF is partially downloaded.

Comment: Can we see the code which retrieves the `content` variable?

Comment: `content = sock.read()`?

Comment: are you sure that the server-side script sends you the whole file? the issue can be on the server side.

Comment: OK. It wasn't on the original answer (Maksym just added it).

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha When I hit the URL via browser, I get the entire file. Is it possible that all browsers will patch it up for me?

Comment: Could you share the link to the pdf doc?

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the file for writing in binary mode (note the `wb`):

```
with open('/tmp/test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

EDIT: Oh, you also have to keep reading until `.read()` returns nothing:

```
url = "http://foo.bar/this/downloads/pdf"
sock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open('/tmp/test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        content = sock.read()
        if not content: break
        f.write(content)
```

From the [`urllib` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

> One caveat: the read() method, if the size argument is omitted or negative, may not read until the end of the data stream; there is no good way to determine that the entire stream from a socket has been read in the general case.

This caveat doesn't appear in the documentation for `urllib2`, but the same concept applies.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clarify: the variable `content` itself is incomplete.

Comment: `>>> content[-30:]`
`'000 n \n0000778751 00000 n \n000'`