# Unable to GET entire page with Python request

Tags: python, http, python-requests, urllib2

I'm trying to get a long JSON response (~75 Mbytes) from a webpage, However I can only receive the first 25 Mbytes or so.

I've used [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) but neither work. I've tried [reading parts in separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102696/python-not-getting-full-response) and [streaming the data](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests), but this doesn't work either.

An example of the data can be found here:

http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?site=14377100&format=json&parameterCd=00060&period=P260W

My code is as follows:

```
r = requests.get("http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?site=14377100&format=json&parameterCd=00060&period=P260W")

usgs_data = r.json() # script breaks here

# Save Longitude and Latitude of river
latitude = usgs_data["value"]["timeSeries"][0]["sourceInfo"]["geoLocation"]["geogLocation"]["latitude"]
longitude = usgs_data["value"]["timeSeries"][0]["sourceInfo"]["geoLocation"]["geogLocation"]["longitude"]

# dictionary of all past river flows in cubic feet per second
river_history = usgs_data['value']['timeSeries'][0]['values'][0]['value']
```

It breaks with:

```
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 13466329 (char 13466328)
```

When the script tries to decode the JSON (i.e. `usgs_data = r.json()`).

This is because the full data hasn't been received and is therefore not a valid JSON object.

Comment: Interesting, it works for me, `r.json()` is not throwing errors..

Comment: @alecxe It does seem to work occasionally for me, and other times is errors out. I guess this supports the claim that it is an issue with their server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the server won't serve more than 13MB of data at a time.

I have tried that URL using a number of HTTP clients including `curl` and `wget`, and all of them bomb out at about 13MB. I have also tried enabling gzip compression (as should you), but the results were still truncated at 13MB after decompression.

You are requesting too much data because the `period=P260W` specifies 260 weeks. If you try setting `period=P52W` you should find that you are able to retrieve a valid JSON response.

To reduce the amount of data transferred, set the `Accept-Encoding` header like this:

```
url = 'http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/'
params = {'site': 11527000, 'format': 'json', 'parameterCd': '00060', 'period': 'P52W'}
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate'})
```

Comment: Actually, `requests` sets the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header by default, so it should be unnecessary for you to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately I need 260 weeks of data for this project, so I'm a little stuck there. Is there anything I can do on my end to allow more information to be pushed by the server? It does seem to work occasionally.

Comment: @Ben: as a workaround I was going to suggest that you use `startDT` and `endDT` parameters to make multiple requests for shorter intervals and then merge the results, however, testing that, even with intervals of just 1 day sometimes results in truncated responses Possibly the requests are being handled by different servers. Try out this idea and if you have trouble with it I think that you might need to take this up with the web service provider.